# How to secure python code in Azure databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks

I am posting here to see if there are proven ways on how to encrypt the python notebooks in Azure data bricks. Basically prevent anyone to look into the workspace and get the machine learning source code written in python or R. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am flagging this question because it needs more focus. Questions that ask "How to do x?" are usually treated in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have **Azure Databricks Premium Plan** you can try this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/access-control/workspace-acl

Also, keep in mind that admins always have access to your workspace, even with access-control enabled.